# how to open android default share dialog in webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, webview

i have created an app using webview and now i want to create a share button (in web and js) to open android default share dialog for user.

But this approach does not work:

```
const sharePromise = navigator.share(data);
```

Because this is not supported in Android Web View.
what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open share by calling custom JS bridge function. Like below

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun share(pMessage: String) {
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, pMessage);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, “ChooserTitle"));  
}
```

Comment: thanks. and how can i call this function from web??

Comment: i did it. its working in android 8 but not in android 10

Comment: strange..it should be work on android 10. Please share your code of webview setting  and JSInterface..